# How can i make infinite loop with timeout function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i make this counter in infinite loop with timeout function. Here is my code. any help highly appreciated.

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n6Ltopc5/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="counter inner">
        <ul>
          <li>
              <h5 class="count">35</h5>
              <p>Years</p>
          </li>
          <li>
              <h5 class="count">150</h5>
              <p>Employees</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.count').each(function () {
$(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text()
}, {
    duration: 2000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function (now) {
        $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
    }
});
});
```

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n6Ltopc5/)**

Comment: What do you man by infinite loop? Do you want the counters to continue forever?

Comment: You could have just edited [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28106396/how-to-make-infinite-loop-with-waiting-time) instead of deleting and reasking.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan have you checked JS fiddle demo. Its a counter i need to restart after 2500 sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a complete callback, reset the counter, and call the animation again.

```
$('.count').each(function anim() {
$(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text()
}, {
    duration: 2000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function (now) {
        $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
    },
    complete: function(){
        $(this).css('counter',0);
        setTimeout(anim.bind(this),1000);
    }
});
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n6Ltopc5/2/)

Answer (score 6):

```
$('.count').each(function () {
    (function rec(self, cnt) {
        $(self).prop('Counter',0).animate({
            Counter: cnt
        }, {
            duration: 2000,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function (now) {
                $(self).text(Math.ceil(now));
            },
            complete : function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    rec(self, cnt);
                }, 400);
            }
        });
    }(this, $(this).text()));
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/n6Ltopc5/4/)